# Using a instance of a method

Tags: java, class, methods

I was wondering if someone could help explain how to call a instance of a class.

For example originally I had a file called "Driver"

Then it has a main method that has all the instances needed for a file to run.

Then in that main file it access another file called with a "Games".

So when I run the program "Driver" which has the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver
{

      public static void main (String[] args)
      {
  
            GameRunner roul = new GameRunner ();
       }
}
```

Then to call an instance of that other file I have something like. Also to make the code work I should have the main method like:
import java.util.*;

```
public class Driver
{

      public static void main (String[] args)
      {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           int number = 3;
           int userChoice = 0;
           GameRunner roul = new GameRunner ();
       }
}
```

Then my other file has something like:
import java.util.*;

```
class GameRunner
{   
     public static void roul(Scanner in, int number, int userChoice)
     {
```

Guessing this is still wrong because the driver class should only have :

```
  GameRunner roul = new GameRunner ();
```

I know it's kinda hard to explain what I'm asking. I hope someone understands.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as "an instance of a method", only an instance of a class (which has methods you can call).

Comment: Ah thats what I meant I think :)

Comment: I'm afraid the best answer to your question, as @Travis suggests, is to read some more tutorials. There's not enough space in a StackOverflow answer to explain all of these concepts.

Comment: Even different instances of the same class share the method code just the variables in each instance are created in a different stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 3;
        int userChoice = 0;
        GameRunner runner = new GameRunner ();

        // The following line will invoke the target method of your game runner instance.
        runner.roul(in, number, userChoice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks figured it his out right as I saw this! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly recommend reading this (official) tutorial from the people who made Java:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html**

*(No, seriously.  Read that tutorial.  I linked to the section specifically on object-oriented programming, which explains what you are asking about.  It's very useful).*

---

Now to answer your question more directly.

Your `roul` method is a "class method" (rather than an "instance method") because it has the keyword `static` in front of its definition.  This means that you invoke it using the name of the class, rather than by using a specific object (instance) that you created.

So in order to call the `roul` method of `GameRunner`, do the following in your `main`:

```
GameRunner.roul(in, number, userChoice);
```

It is not necessary to instantiate `GameRunner` unless it has a non-static method that you need to invoke.  So unless that's the case, don't do the following:

```
GameRunner roul = new GameRunner ();
```

Finally, note that the names of your arguments do not have to be the same as the names of your parameters, as long as their *types* are the same.  The "parameters" are the variables you used when you defined the method.  The "arguments" the actual variables you pass to the method.

For example, a method definition has parameters:

```
public static void myMethod(int parameter1, int parameter2) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Whereas a method invocation has arguments that can have a different name:

```
MyClass.myMethod(number1, number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the class and method static then call like this:

```
GameRunner.roul(); // pass in arguments if needed
```

Comment: The class doesn't need to be declared static. Java doesn't have static outer classes.

Answer (score -1):

public static void run() is the entry point into your application you don't need another one. it looks like you need to brush up on Object Oriented basics.

if you're trying to make a game perhaps you could start with a tutorial? i would suggest using a game library like Lightweight Java Game Library. go ahead and google for some tutorials.

Comment: Where is `public static void run()` defined? It definitely _isn't_ the entry point to any Java program.

Comment: So where would the same like game.roul(in, number) go?